# Re-apply click binding on context switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several `<div class="some_class">` . I bind to it an `event` to it through

```
$('.some_class').on('click',function() {...})
```

Now. When I change context and I creat dynamically new `<div class="some_class">` the event is not binded enough. How I can solve this without repeating the binding in the context switch `function` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$(document).on('click','.some_class',function() {...})
```

instead of

```
$('.some_class').on('click',function() {...})
```

For more information, see [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Answer (score 2):

try using:

```
$(document).on('click', '.some_class', function() {...})
```

instead